# Borders around ImageIcons appear to have zero border, hgap and vgap are zero, still empty space between ImageIcons

Tags: java, eclipse

There is a persistent empty space around the ImageIcons. I created new empty borders on all the objects like so:

`array[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`

set the hgap and vgap to zero on two diffrent layouts:

`frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));`

`//frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(screenSize.height/15,screenSize.width/15,0,0));`

and tried setting the gaps negative, on advice from another post on here. None of these seem to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the all of settings of your `GridLayout` By default it has some margins and such. Though I might be wrong, it occurs to me this is Swing and not SWT.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me when I use a JLabel. You don't even need to use an EmptyBorder.

Maybe the problem is that your images have a transparent border. Or maybe the problem is that you are using another component.

If you need more help than post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.